# Filtering on inverse relationships with Realm Swift

Tags: swift, filter, realm, predicate

really struggling with something that I think should be easy.

Using Swift 3.0, RealmSwift 2.4.2

I have two models, one which has an inverse relationship to the other using LinkingObjects.

```
class SetModel: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let questions = List<QuestionModel>()
}

class QuestionModel: Object {
    dynamic var level = ""
    let sets = LinkingObjects(fromType: QuestionModel.self, property: "questions")
}
```

QuestionModels have multiple SetModels. SetModels have multiple QuestionsModels.

A SetModel can have a name such as 'Food', 'Sport', 'Travel' etc.

At some point in my code I need to find a subset of QuestionModels that equate to a number of different filtering options, one of which is Sets.
i.e. get all questions that are 'easy' that are in certain sets.

I am given a number of Sets, such as 'Food' & 'Travel' and need to find all questions that have that set in their 'sets' attribute.

```
fileprivate func applyFilters(objects: Results<QuestionModel>) -> Results<QuestionMode> {
    var res = objects

    // I have a session attribute that stores the values I need to filter on, 
    // one of which is a List<SetModels>
    if (session.sets.count > 0) {
        // These are the things I've tried, and the error messages :(

        for s in session.sets {
            // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', 
            // reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use 
            // aggregate operations'
            res = res.filter("sets.name == \(s.name!)")
        }
        for s in session.sets {
            // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', 
            // reason: 'Predicate with ANY modifier must compare a KeyPath with 
            // RLMArray with a value'
            res = res.filter("ANY sets.name == \(s.name!)")
        }

        for s in session.sets {
            // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
            // reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY sets == SetModel
            res = res.filter("ANY sets == \(s)")
        }
        // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', 
        // reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate 
        // operations'
        res = res.filter("sets.name IN \({'Food', 'Travel'})")
    }

    // Filter on level
    res = res.filter("level == 'easy'")

    return res
}
```

Edit: Here's a po of a question.sets, which shows I can access sets and there is data in there

```
po self.questionModel.sets
LinkingObjects<SetModel> (
[0] SetModel {
    uuid = 5899cb786f6986.79052132;
    name = Action;
    questions = RLMArray <0x7f9a529a6910> (
        [0] QuestionModel {
            question = What can you climb?;
            responses = Tree;
        },
        [1] QuestionModel {
            question = How could you get into town?;
            responses = Bus;
        }
    );
},
[1] SetModel {
    uuid = 5899cbc2938b87.61048461;
    name = Travel;
    questions = RLMArray <0x7f9a52c05d60> (
        [0] QuestionModel {
            question = How could you get into town?;
            responses = Bus;
        }
    );
}
)
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

well, I've figured it out after a day...

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(sets, $s, $s.name IN %@).@count > 0", ['Demo', 'Food'] )
res = res.filter(predicate)
```

Honestly, sometimes I feel like an apprentice magician just saying spells at random :)